# Django 2.0 Annotate an Annotation Queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a set of `inspectors`, each with a number of projects that they work on, and get paid for based on their `pay_rate`.  My goal is to roll up the average pay rate of `inspectors` based on what company they are working for. 
 If an inspector works on more than one job, I want to use his average `pay_rate`.

The following code SHOULD do this, but it does not.

```
i = InspectorProject.objects.all()
uniques = i.order_by('inspector', 
                'project__prime_consultant__name').values('inspector', 
                'project__prime_consultant__name')\
           .annotate(pay_rate=Avg('pay_rate'), bill_rate=Avg('bill_rate'))
# the above code works as expected. here's where it gets fishy.
companies = uniques.order_by(.order_by('project__prime_consultant__name')
                   .values('project__prime_consultant__name')\
                   .annotate(avg_pay=Avg('pay_rate'), avg_bill=Avg('bill_rate'))\
```

The last line there gives me a `keyError: 'pay_rate'` on the annotation.  What this means to me is that the second annotation is not recognizing the attribute/column/field that is created by the first annotation.

1) Why?

2) How do I get around this?

I include the `bill_rate` to be thorough, but the problem is clearly in the second annotation's inability to recognize the first's generated field.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this because of your `values` call. After that, any further manipulations will only have the fields you specify in `values`. Move that to after the annotate or add `pay_rate` and `bill_rate` to the `values` call.